# How to get new widget's width and height after being scaled using Transformer.scale

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code for scaling `widget`

```
double  scale= 0.8;
double widthAndHeight = 200 ;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onScaleUpdate: (detail){
              scale=detail.scale;
              setState(() {});
            },
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: scale,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              width: widthAndHeight,
              height: widthAndHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The scaling is done correctly but I noticed that the width and height of the original container which is 200 remain exactly the same even though the scaling has been changed and updated !!

**Question** : How can I get the new real width and height of the container after each scalin
and  updating proces

**Note** : I tried to used `LayoutBuilder()` to try to find the new width and height, but it also gives the same first value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, Transform will not update your `widthAndHeight`, it just calculate new width and height with your scale value.

So the easiest way to get new width and height is write your own function :

```
double getNewWidthAndHeight => scale * widthAndHeight
```

Comment: You have no idea how mush you make me happy with this useful answer after suffering for hours  . you hit what i want exactly , thanks !!